# Windows 7 - sharing file - slow seek time?

Tags: windows-7, file-sharing

I do not want to copy the files. I simply have video files (.flv) on one computer and I would like another computer user to watch them without copying. Playback is fine, but seek time (as in if you move the cursor to skip some portion of the video) takes forever!  I thought wireless speed might be the culprit, so I wired the two computer. Maybe I saw some improvement but still so bad. It's 1 Gbps! (I know real speed will vary, but before I monitor real speed and such, do I have reasonable issue? Or am I bound to have very slow seek time?)

What is going on?

I must mention some of these files are huge!

Comment: What player are you using? In addition, I doubt that you actually have 1Gbps of bandwidth, but that the network says that that is the capacity.

Comment: @soandos I agree, but what is causing it to not reach 1 Gbps? Both computers are directly wired to each other. I'm using real player.

Comment: your network card does not generally support that kind of speed, and the computer is not able to read the file that fast. I would try to use VLC, and see if that changes anything. Right now, I think what is going on is that it is loading the whole file up until that point, then playing from there. I know that VLC has good support for streaming and such, so see if that fixes it.

Comment: No problem, posting that as the answer then.

Answer (score 0):

You must also be using a player that supports this behavior while streaming. If your player does not, then what it will do is load the whole file up until that point, then play.

A player that supports this is VLC.

Comment: If I move the cursor to almost end, it still does take forever, but once it recovers, it is able to seek any other duration in middle pretty easily. Does it seem like it's still copying instead of streaming? :(

Comment: on some video files, it's failing to seek altogether, while real player is able to do the job.

Comment: Yes. Did you try the steps listed [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-VLC-Media-Player-to-Stream-Multimedia-to-Another-Computer)?

Comment: First, I'm having a hard time getting it to work. Second, it leaves too much control in the sender computer's hand. I want it to be like a website where a user can click on any video he wants and be able to stream it too.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that this was just smaller thing. for that, look at something like [this](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html)